# Modal Segue Causing Black Screen

Tags: ios, swift, segue, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal segue which brings in a new view controller which has a view inside of it, and a transparent background.[image] 
So when I run the app initially and press the button to start the modal segue, the View Controller is brought in and it looks like this since the View Controller has a transparent background:
[image] However when I go another tab, and then come back to the view controller I was at initially, it looks like this: 
[image]
How can I make it so it doesnt show the black background but the view controller background, and not darken the tab bar using SWIFT?

**Objectives**

- Make it so the background is not black, but show's the original `ViewController`
- Make it so the tab bar does not darken into a gradient like it does.

Comment: did you check your viewdidappear method?

Comment: @longbow  What would I need to look for exactly?

Comment: well basically you can do the same stuff as you would in viewdidload to set up your whole background thing, but that is hard to judge without any code seen - the tab bar darkens most likely because you instantiate it multiple times

Comment: @longbow I didn't use any code. Just a Segue that Presents modally, over current context, with the default transition.

Comment: @longbow What code would I need to add? Thanks again.

Comment: So you have a modal up on the screen and you can access the tab bar? That shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @TravisM. Yes, it works. I can access the tab bar.

Comment: why do you even need the modal window? why not just put the cpx picture and the red menu into the "Home" VC?

Comment: @longbow because it's a good animated functionality that doesn't clutter the screen

Comment: i am strictly talking about vc hierarchy - why dont you put everything into the home vc and then you can still animate in the middle orange view - the black screen i guess is because the tab bar controller loses track of the parent VC where you modally presented the orange box

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your view controller Presentation is set to 'Over Current Context'.  The section in your Interface Builder where all your view controller settings are contains Transition Style and right below it is Presentation.

[Interface Builder Settings Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkFSG.png)